# How to order by COUNT(*) of unique entries in GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, query, group-by, count, mariadb-10.5

I search through a tag_map as

```
SELECT ArticleID,COUNT(*) AS C FROM WordMap 
WHERE WordID IN(
SELECT WordID FROM Words WHERE Word IN ('word1', 'word2')
) 
GROUP BY ArticleID 
ORDER BY C DESC
```

I want to get article ids in which all words (here word1 and word2) appear first.

The above query returns in order of the number (e.g., if word1 appears 100 times).

NOTE: WordMap table is huge, and this is the reason I went for sub-query rather than JOIN.

Comment: Use having keyword

Comment: `ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT WordID) DESC, C DESC`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ it works beautifully. If you post it as an answer, it can help others.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer. I have stopped (mostly) posting on SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

I answer this question because @ypercubeᵀᴹ was reluctant to do so, and I thought it might help others.

The tricky part is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT WordID)` instead of `COUNT(*)`, as the latter does not consider the repetition.

As suggested by @ypercubeᵀᴹ, the ultimate solution is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT WordID)` and `COUNT(*)` together to have a perfect order considering the number of unique words and total occurrence.

The query looks like

```
SELECT ArticleID,COUNT(*) AS C, COUNT(DISTINCT WordID) AS D FROM WordMap 
WHERE WordID IN(
SELECT WordID FROM Words WHERE Word IN ('word1', 'word2')
) 
GROUP BY ArticleID 
ORDER BY D DESC, C DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `wordmap` is a many-to-many mapping table between `articles` (via `article_id`) and `words` via `word_id`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can verify.

I suggest that that is "over-normalized".  Instead, have

```
 CREATE TABLE wordmap (
     article_id INT ...,
     word VARCHAR(77) ...,
     PRIMARY KEY(article_id, word),
     INDEX(word, article_id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then

```
SELECT  ArticleID, COUNT(*) AS C
    FROM  WordMap
    WHERE  Word IN ('word1', 'word2') 
    GROUP BY  ArticleID
    ORDER BY  C DESC
```

will say which articles have that has either of those words.  The `COUNT` is indicating whether 1 or 2 different words are present.  That is probably not what you wanted.

If that is not what you wanted, then rephrase the question.